# make somehow changed the recipe and not following the Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Somehow, make is not following the makefile and generated the recipe itself. The recipe of compiling c source to .o is:

```
  @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ffreestanding -std=gnu99 -c -o $@ $< -I /usr/include/multiboot/ -nostdlib -I include
```

but somehow, it changed it to this:

```
i686-elf-gcc -Wextra -Wall -O2 -s -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast   -c -o cexpand.o cexpand.c
```

which of cause, making the compiler complains about the absence of a few header files. Also, --trace reported this:

```
<builtin>: update target 'cexpand.o' due to: cexpand.c
```

Now, is there any way to stop it from doing that?

The whole Makefile:

```
//just incase someone asked, it's from my wip os NetDOS-32. Also, I'm not really an expert in Makefiles.
OBJ=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
CC=i686-elf-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wextra -Wall -O2 -s -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast
NASM=nasm
NFLAGS=-felf32 
LD=i686-elf-gcc
all: os.iso 

os.iso:kernel.elf
    -@mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub
    @cp kernel.elf isodir/boot/kernel.elf
    @cp grub.cfg isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    @sudo grub-mkrescue -o os.iso isodir
    
boot.o:boot.asm
    @echo "[NASM($(NASM))] $<"
    @$(NASM) -o $@ $<  $(NFLAGS)
%.o:%.c mm/%.c font.h Makefile 
    @echo "[CC($(CC))] $<" 
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -ffreestanding -std=gnu99 -c -o $@ $< -I /usr/include/multiboot/ -nostdlib -I include  
kernel.elf:$(OBJ) boot.o
    @echo "[LD($(LD))] $(OBJ) boot.o"
    @$(LD)  -Tlinker.ld -o $@ -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib  boot.o  $(OBJ) -lgcc   $(CFLAGS) 
clean:
    -rm *.o *.elf 
test: all
    qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom os.iso
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule looks like this:

```
%.o:%.c mm/%.c font.h Makefile
```

A pattern rule will ONLY apply if ALL the prerequisites either already exist or can be created.  If not, then the rule does not apply and make will continue looking for another rule.  In this case, there are built-in rules that will match and it will use those.

So, my expectation is that for the `cexpand.o` target this pattern rule doesn't apply.  Most likely because the file `mm/cexpand.c` does not exist.